# Using OR inside click function

Tags: jquery

Can you in jQuery do something like `(a || b).click()`?

I am trying to have something happen when either a or b is clicked. In the sample below, I want wherever it says `button[i]`, for it to have a `menubutton[i]` next to it, so that everything can happen either when a `button[i]` or `menubutton[i]` is clicked.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  $(button[i]).click(function() {
    if (divClosed[i]) {
      $('#icons-pattern-main').css({
        'height': '920px',
        'clip-path': 'none',
        'transition': '0.2s linear'
      });
      $('#text').css('display', 'none')
      $('#textpers').css('display', 'flex')
      $('#textpers').text(pers[i])
      $('.header').mouseleave(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('#textpers').text("τι τάξη είσαι;")
        }, 5000);
      })
      for (let x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
        (divClosed[x]) = true
        $(ShEl[x]).hide();
      }
      for (let x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
        $(ShElinner[x]).hide();
      }
      divClosed[i] = false
      $(ShEl[i]).css('display', 'flex');
      if (i > 1) {
        $('#icons-pattern-main').css('height', '520')
        for (let x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
          $(option[x]).click(function() {
            $(ShElinner[x]).show()
            $(ShEl[i]).hide()
            $('#icons-pattern-main').css('height', '920')
            subOpen = true
            if (subOpen) {
              $(button[i]).click(function() {
                $(ShElinner[x]).hide()
                subOpen = false
              });
            }
          });
        }
      }
    } else {
      $('#icons-pattern-main').css({
        'height': '420px',
        'clip-path': 'polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 59%, 44% 59%, 50% 100%, 56% 59%, 0 59%)',
        'transition': '0.2s linear'
      });
      divClosed[i] = true;
      $(ShEl[i]).hide()
      $(ShElinner).hide()
      $('#text').css('display', 'flex')
      $('#textpers').css('display', 'none')
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.class1, .class2').on('click', some_function);
```

Or:

```
$('.class1').add('.class2').on('click', some_function);
```

This also works with existing objects:

```
const $class1 = $('.class1');
const $class2 = $('.class2');
$class1.add($class2).on('click', some_function);
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, You can select multiple elements using **CSS selectors**.

So you'd separate multiple selectors with a *comma* (`,`) like this:

```js
$(".a,.b").click()
```

---

In your case, you can add elements to the selector with the `.add()` function as Lennard K suggested like this:

```js
$(button[i]).add(menubutton[i]).click()
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work on my code. is it because my a and b are variables with multiple id's inside or am I missing something? Would you use this logic on the code i've provided above? a would be button[i] and b would be something like menubutton[i]. Thanks!